# How to return a key value ONLY if ALL the foreign keys in another table have a certain status (ORACLE)

Tags: sql, oracle

How do I return the key (not a primary key): bwb_procesinstantie_id of the table wachtbox ONLY if ALL 'foreign key' values in the related table status have the status = "B"

Functionality: A process contains several rel_code. But the process can only be further processed if all the rel_codes have the right status...in this case 'B'.

This is the table wachtbox. As you can see the bwb_procesinstantie_id is the same in all three records.

[image: wachtbox]

This is the table status

[image: status]

The distinct bwb_processinstantie_id value may only be returned if all the bgst_status fields have the value 'B'

So in the above example. NO bwb_procesinstantie_id should be returned because one of the linked records has status  'N'.

Comment: what is the relation between these two tables?

Comment: 1. Can the status be `null`? 2. Can there be "key" values that do not appear in the child table AT ALL? If so, how should those keys be handled? Logically, they should be included in the output (ALL the rows in the second table, for this key, have status = 'B', if there are no such rows to begin with; this is basic logic and basic set theory); but often, in practice, users don't see it that way.

Comment: @eshirvana. rel_code is the link. In table wachtbox it is called bwb_rel_code the one in the other table bgst_rel_code

Comment: @mathguy Status is supposed to never be null. How should that be handled? I only want a procesinstantie_id to be returned if ALL the values in table status have status = B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
SELECT t1.bwb_processinstantie_id
FROM t1
JOIN t2
  ON t1.bwb_rel_code = t2.bstg_rel_code
GROUP BY t1.bwb_processinstantie_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(CASE WHEN t2.bgst_status = 'B' THEN 1 END)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select bwb_processinstantie_id
from   t1
where  bwb_processinstantie_id not in
         (
           select bwb_processinstantie_id
           from   t2
           where  lnnvl(bgst_status = 'B')
         )
;
```

This assumes that a key from the parent table must appear in the output, if it doesn't appear in the child table AT ALL. (This is the mathematical definition: given any condition whatsoever, even one that is clearly false, it is still true that all the elements of the **empty set** satisfy the condition - for the simple reason that there are NO elements that must satisfy the condition to begin with.)

Moreover, the solution assumes the id is primary key in the parent table, and it is constrained to `not null` in the second table. (Otherwise the subquery in the `not in` condition must add a `where` condition: that the `ID` be non-null.)

The solution allows for the "status" to be `null` - `lnnvl(status = 'B')` is true if `status = 'B'` is either false or `unknown` (which will be the case when the status is `null`).

Comment: Thank you for your time! I have marked Lukasz's solution as the one that solved my problem. Your answer contained: "select bwb_processinstantie_id  from   t2". But I do not have this columin in the 2nd table.